# Emacs solarized theme looks weird in terminal and dark mode does not work

Tags: linux, emacs, gnu

I tried installing [this theme in emacs](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized).

I downloaded the folder `emacs-color-theme-solarized` and put it into the `.emacs.d/` directory.
I created a file `init.el` in the same directory and put the following into that file:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/emacs-color-theme-solarized/")                          
(load-theme 'solarized t)
```

When I did `eval-buffer` or restarting emacs it looked like this:

[image: this]

The font is not readable. When I start emacs in GUI it looks better.

[image: better]

I want to use the dark solarized theme so I followed the instructions on the website and did `M-x customize-variable frame-background-mode` and pressed on the button `Value Menu` and set it to dark and then saved by `C-x C-s`. I restarted but it still is the light theme. [Here is the a screenshot from the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLrSi.png).

How can I fix the problems in the terminal and activate the dark mode?

Comment: Change your terminal's colour scheme.

Comment: not a programming question - belongs to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue you need to change your terminal settings.  How you do this depends on which terminal you have.  The problem is that solarized themes want a terminal running in 16 color mode where the colors are very specifically defined.  You can set up your terminal to use these colors by finding it in the [solarized github repository](https://github.com/altercation/solarized).  Once your terminal is using the right colors everything will just work.